# Flutter give Streambuilder initalData

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have a `Streambuilder` that takes Firebase Firestore snapshot as a Stream and I would like to add `initalData` to the `Streambuilder`.

How can I pass `initalData` to the `Streambuilder`?

The Code:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("events")
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) {
      return NoDataRelatedLocation();
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
    } else {
      return new RelatedLocationListing(
        relatedLocationList: snapshot.data.docs,
      );
    }
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `initialData` to `StreamBuilder`:

```
StreamBuilder(
   initialData: ..... // <~~~ add it here. 
   stream: ... 
   builder: ...
```

You just need to make sure that your `initialData` matches that type of data coming from the stream. Since `QuerySnapshot` is a Firebase specific type, you should map your stream to a data type that you can create and that's known to you.

Here's a pseudo code:

```
initialData: [MyDataType()],
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("events")
      .snapshots().map((snapshot) => MyDataType.fromMap(snapshot.doc));
```

Comment: Thank you that was actually the part I was stuck with I didn't know what Type I should give the initalData but I hope I am able to do it with your Instruction

Comment: @EnviroApps to make sure you get the type right, assign it to stream builder such in `StreamBuilder<List<MyType>>`, so Dart analyzer can check that your mapping is correct. (btw, I'm just assuming here it's a List of MyType for example)

Comment: The best way to get it right with the Type etc. would be to make a ModelClass right?

Comment: @EnviroApps you can do that but also you can use `RelatedLocationListing` constructor directly when you map the snapshots as long as you can create that type for initialData and you can map `QuerySnapshot` to it. They are just different ways of doing the same thing..

Comment: Ok thank you I am still learning and sometimes things are pretty difficult for me